# What's causing this wait chain lock?

Tags: com, locking, wait, chain

I have an application which calls a com library.
For certain reason the com library stops working. It doesn't hang, it just seems to be waiting for something.
My Application is waiting for the com library to respond too.

I checked the wait chain:

[image: Wait Chain]

---

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this issue ?

Why the App.exe has no thread ID ?

Thank you

Comment: It appears that `App.exe` is an out-of-process COM server, and `COMLIB.exe` makes a COM call on it. For whatever reason, the server is not returning from that call in a timely manner.

Comment: App.exe might not have a thread id because it's running as another user, perhaps local service credentials.  Try checking the wait chain with task manager running as administrator.